# Spark python performance of data frame filter

Tags: python, pyspark

Below takes over 10 minutes to complete although source table has only 155 rows. I was expecting seconds here, not minutes. Anyone can see something obvious why it is so slow? I am relatively new to Python. I have already checked with SQL expression and with col function. Surprisingly the fastest one was SQL version. I also tried filter instead of where.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, StringType, IntegerType, BooleanType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

schema = StructType([
    StructField('FOLDER_ID', IntegerType(), False),
    StructField('NAME', StringType(), False),
    StructField('PATH', StringType(), True)
])

df = spark.createDataFrame([],schema)
list_df = df.collect()
df_FOLDER = read("_IncortaMetadata.FOLDER")
list_FOLDER = df_FOLDER.collect()

for folder in list_FOLDER:
    folderId = folder["ID"]
    parentId = folder["PARENT"]
    folderName = folder["NAME"]

    df_PARENT = df_FOLDER.where(df_FOLDER.ID == parentId)
    pathString = ''

    while df_PARENT.count() > 0:
        if df_PARENT.count() > 1:
            pathString = pathString + ' - error - multiple parent folders!'
            break
        else:
            list_PARENT = df_PARENT.collect()
            parentRow = list_PARENT[0]

            if parentRow["ID"] == parentRow["PARENT"]:
                break
            else:
                if pathString != '':
                    pathString = pathString + ' > ' + parentRow["NAME"]
                else:
                    pathString = parentRow["NAME"]

            df_PARENT = df_FOLDER.where(df_FOLDER.ID == parentRow["PARENT"])
            
    list_df.append({'FOLDER_ID':folderId, 'NAME':folderName, 'PATH':pathString})

df = spark.createDataFrame(list_df, schema)
save(df)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67976968/3238085  << you can use a profiler to see where most of the time is spent.